# A body with zero total energy in a conservative field

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, energy-conservation, potential-energy

So imagine a mass $M$ is kept fixed at a point. Another mass $m$ is at rest at infinity. Hence it has net zero energy. Now imagine the mass $m$ starts moving towards $M$ due to the gravitational force. At a point quite close to $M$, say at distance $R$, the body would have gained quite some kinetic energy right? It will me moving at very high velocity as it has come all the way from infinity. However it's Gravitational potential energy will also decrease so that it's net energy is always zero. How does an object flying with such a high velocity have like zero total energy? If it has zero total energy can it still do work? Like if another object is placed in its path, can mass m do work on it? If so then how does it's energies change?

Comment: what gravitational force?  If the masses are infinitely far, this force will be $0$.  Or are there other masses in your problem?

Answer (score 1):

> How does an object flying with such a high velocity have like zero total energy?

You already answered this yourself:

> it's Gravitational potential energy will also decrease so that it's net energy is always zero.

---

> If it has zero total energy can it still do work?

Of course. For example, the GPE could become negative and the energy could go to doing work on some other object rather than increasing the KE of this object.

Potential energy is only defined to an additive constant. Its absolute value is immaterial to the the physics of a system. And there is nothing wrong with potential energy becoming negative.

In fact when you (as you did in this example) choose the additive constant to define gravitational potential energy to be zero with the objects infinitely distant from each other, then the GPE will always be either 0 or negative in that system.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the answer. So when the mass m does work on the other thing (in this system), the GPE, The KE , and the work done by mass m, all add up to zero right? And this work done will be taken from what would have gone to increase KE right?  Also, isn't energy defined as the ability to do work? Then how did something with zero total energy do postive work on something. I know all of this should happen but I'm confused and don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is a conceptual mistake in your scenario: physically, there is no such thing as an 'infinite' distance between two points. In physics, we use concepts such as 'at some point in infinity' when there are other factors to be considered, and we know that numerically, one of them will be much larger than the other. In said case, 'at infinity' is a mathematical tool to simplify our equations.

In the case of gravity, the potential scales as $\dfrac{1}{r}$, so if we want to get rid of such a term in an equation, we know that mathematically $\lim_{r \rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{1}{r}=0$. That is the reason we are allowed to say that 'at infinity' the mass m feels no potential from M.

I believe your questions should be more like "when do we take the potential into consideration?" And that will depend on the specific scenario you are considering, and the questions you're trying to answer about the system.
For example, if you had a system of 3 masses, $M_1, M_2$, and $m$, where $m$ is, say, one hundred thousand billion times smaller than both $M_1$ and $M_2$, you can probably simplify to $m=0$ and for most purposes, the description of the system would be the same.

If the system you're considering is only two masses and nothing else, the distance between them is always a relevant parameter and shouldn't be simplified. What you described is simplifying a two body system to a one body system, and so will reach different conclusions.

As an example of this, your scenario actually has a contradiction: if the mass is at rest 'at infinity', it will not feel the gravitational force ever, and therefore it should never move towards M *because* of the gravitational force (since it doesn't feel it).

I would even say that this type of considerations are actually one of the pivots of physics, and a key ability to a physicist.